# Android calculate height of child View When overflow

Tags: android, height, overflow

I have nested LinearLayouts where Parent height is 90 but the child view may have different heights according to the text set inside it and may overflow its parent. I Want to animate Parent to final Height of child but both methods of **getHeight()** on child and **getMeasuredHeight()** on parent, return **90** not **400**.

[image]

```
parent.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
targetHeight = parent.getMeasuredHeight();
//returns 90
```

and also

```
View child=((ViewGroup) parent).getChildAt(0);
int targetHeight=child.getHeight();
//returns 90
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Hope it'll work.

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = yourView.getLayoutParams();
int height = params.height;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    LayoutParams paramsChild = child.getLayoutParams();

    LayoutParams paramsParent = parent.getLayoutParams();
    paramsParent.height = paramsChild.height;
    parent.setLayoutParams(paramsParent);
```